# inList constraints in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails

I am converting an application from Grails to Java and need to find the equivalent of the inList constraints in grails to the spring/hibernate equivalent.

```
     static constraints = {
        stringValue(inList:['testValue', 'testValue', 'testValue', 'testValue', 'test value', 'test&value'], nullable:false)
   }
```

I am not sure what the hibernate/spring equivalent is for this type of constraint.

**UPDATE**

I tried using an enum  but I need to include special characters such as & and spaces so to my knowledge only strings will work since I have to pull these values from a database.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in constraint, but you can write it yourself. Why don't you use an enum rather than a String?

Comment: as said, an enum would do the job. or using a SET in Hibernate

Comment: I am going to set the variable to an enum as described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267520/declare-enum-variable-in-java-bean

Comment: Regarding your update, you should use an attribute converter to convert your enum to a string and vice-versa. Google for "JPA attribute converter"